# How do I submit auto-renewable subscription + app for review in iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload the first version of an app that has auto-renewable subscription IAP products associated with it. The products are all Ready to Submit, and I see a note at the top of the manage in app purchases page that says:

> • Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app
>   version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version
>   Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.

However, when I go to the version details page, I do not see an In-App Purchases section, and don't see any other way to specify which In-App Purchases I want to submit along with the app.

If I subsequently add a non-renewable subscription product to the app, I do see the In-App Purchases section on the version details page, but it only contains the non-renewable subscription product, not the auto-renewable subscription product that I actually want to submit.

Does anyone know what else I need to do to allow the auto-renewable subscription IAP products to be submitted for review along with this version of the app when I submit my binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decided to submit the app with non-renewable subscriptions to see what would happen. When we did this, the option to submit the auto-renewable subscriptions appeared in the "Manage In-App Purchases" page.

It looks like the developer guide and the messages in iTunes Connect that refer to using the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page to control submission of subscriptions does not apply to auto-renewable subscriptions.